# How to fix my math class?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my code:

```
class math():
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
class pythagorus(math):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        math.__init__(self, x, y)
    def __str__(self):
        import math
        return math.sqrt(x**2+y**2)

q = pythagorus(4, 5)
print(q)
```

How do I make a function out of a class, if that makes any sense, I want to return the result of math.sqrt(x**2+y**2), but I can't seem to get it to work? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not just make it a function? `def pythagoras(x, y): return math.sqrt(x**2 + y**2)`?

Comment: because I already know how to use functions, i'm trying to learn how to implement my old programs with classes to practice :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to refer to `self` to access attributes on your class:

```
class pythagoras(math):
    def __str__(self):
        import math
        return str(math.sqrt(self.x**2 + self.y**2))
```

A `__str__` method *must* return a string value, so using `__str__` for this is a little.. weird. No need to override the `__init__` method, you didn't do anything new in it.

You may want to name your *base class* something other than `math` so you don't mask the module (and not need to import it in your `__str__` method). Best practice is to use CamelCase names for classes; `Math` would be a better choice.

For this kind of operation, I'd just use a function instead:

```
import math

def pythagoras(x, y)
    return math.sqrt(x**2 + y**2)
```

At best, you'd make `pythagoras` a *method* on your math class:

```
import math

class Math():
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x, self.y = x, y

    def pythagoras(self):
        return math.sqrt(self.x ** 2 + self.y ** 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you **absolutely have to** do it like this, correct the following:

1. Do not mix names - `math` is both a module and a class. Use a different name.
2. `math.__init__(self, x, y)` is meaningless. To initialize your members inherited from a parent class, use `super()`. In this case, you don't have to do it since you're not doing anything other than what your parent class' constructor is doing.
3. `str` must return a string.

To that end:

```
import math
class Point():
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

class Pythagorus(Point):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        # Possibly other things need to be done, but not in this case.
        super().__init__(x, y)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(math.sqrt(self.x ** 2 + self.y ** 2))
```

I would strongly suggest to use a simple design for this, like a function, unless you're required to do it this way (e.g. homework).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to override the `__init__` on the child class since you aren't changing the implementation.

Since your `__str__` method is generic, it should be part of the parent. The child should just implement specific object functionality.

```
import math as _math

class Math():
   """ A generic math class """
   def __init__(self, x, y):
      self.x = x
      self.y = y
      self.result = 0

   def __str__(self):
       return str(self.result)

class Pythagorus(Math):
    def calculate(self):
        self.result = _math.sqrt(self.x ** 2 + self.y ** 2)

obj = Pythagorus(8,5)
obj.calculate()
print(obj)
```